# Add select with javascript in Symfony 2

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I want to raise an issue that arose me and do not know how to fix it .
Suppose I want to create a dynamic select , ie , if a select product , if I add or remove a product, select automatically updated. for example, could make the query in the controller like this:

```
$products = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')->findAll();
```

Then render it in this way:

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:myfolder:mytwig.html.twig', array("products" => $products));
```

And finally in my template , create my select like this:

```
<select>
{% for product in products %}
<option value="{{ product.name }}">{{ product.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

my problem is I have a select where the user chooses to buy a product , and if you want to add another , by a button labeled "Add" enable a javascript , and so another select where you can choose another product is generated.

I've already made the javascript file, but if I use a twig for in the product not recognize me , ie , I can not add this with javascript:

```
<select>
    {% for product in products %}
    <option value="{{ product.name }}">{{ product.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

long time since I am with this, please , if you can help me do . thanks

Comment: That arose you ? not sure you wanted to say that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that including your Javascript in your Twig file, and not in a separate file, enables you to use `{{ }}`, resolving your problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with JavaScript alone, if you change your template to generate a "base" copy of your `<SELECT>` like this (assuming jQuery for brevity):

```
<div id='products_list'>
    <select>
    {% for product in products %}
      <option value="{{ product.name }}">{{ product.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
<button id='AddProduct'>Add</button>
<script>
  $('#AddProduct').on('click', function () {
    var base = $('#products_list select:first');
    base.parent().append(base.clone());
  });
</script>
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9s4v1eh/))